# Create virtual machine using qcow2 as storage (virt-manager)

Tags: debian, qemu, kvm

I am running debian wheezy. virt-manager is version 0.9.1. As per online documentation it should be possible to create a virtual machine using qcow2 storage, as per [this link](http://opennodecloud.com/documentation/howtos/kvm-vm-management-with-virt-manager-gui/).

However from my version the dialog box looks rather like this:

[image]

And during install process it is not possible to select anything but 'raw' storage:

[image]

I have tried creating the the qcow2 image [outside](http://virt-tools.org/learning/install-with-command-line/#disk) of the interface using:

```
# qemu-img create -f qcow2 guest.qcow2  8192
Formatting 'guest.qcow2', fmt=qcow2 size=8192 encryption=off cluster_size=65536
```

For some reason the file size does look kind of odd:

```
# ls -altr guest.qcow2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 197120 juil. 24 15:13 guest.qcow2
```

If I select this storage and then pursue with a regular Window 7 pro installation, the installer report that the disk size is simply 0 and cannot continue.

Any recommendation on where to do from here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was a simple typo from the link I used:

- http://virt-tools.org/learning/install-with-command-line/#disk

The line:

```
# qemu-img create -f qcow2 /var/lib/libvirt/images/guest.qcow2 8192
```

should really read (missing trailing 'M'):

```
# qemu-img create -f qcow2 /var/lib/libvirt/images/guest.qcow2 8192M
```

Just for reference, using qcow2 (even with virtio) is terribly slow for a Windows 7 VM, as per [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/407842/incredibly-slow-kvm-disk-performance-qcow2-disk-files-virtio), so I ended up using `raw` storage.